# Help with WebDav protocol?

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, webdav

We want to use WebDav ProtoCol for FileTransfer and other file related activies through our client application.

So here are my basic questions:

1- How to setup WebDav on my system?
2- Can I install WebDav on Linux ?

3- If want to program using .NET and  C# , do I need to add external library or `System.net` `and System.xml` Namespace are enough?

**Edit:**

1- I am new to WebDAv and any link will be helpfull on How to Setup WebDAV on XP and Linux.

2- What Libraries and Commands I need to used inorder to ineract with WebDAV server , example: Which command I should send through my C# client to WebDav server so that I can get the list of Folders on the WebDav server.

Thanks,

Subhen

Comment: I downvoted because your questions aren't specific enough. What did you try, and where did you fail?

Comment: Updated the Post. Hope I am clear this time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I install WebDav on Linux ?

You can do anything on Linux you can do on any other OS, and more!

> How to setup WebDav on my system?

Apache server provides a WebDAV extension module. For more complicated setups you can use things like SabreDAV on php or roll your own server/methods library in Java, Python, perl, ruby. Or you can work from existing projects which strive to implement WebDAV. There are actually very few open source or free projects providing a *complete* WebDAV implementation.

> What Libraries and Commands

In any language, you will need to implement a server backend which is able to - more of less complete - answer a number of not-so-common HTTP methods like PUT or PROPFIND. Read the RFCs!

Answer (score 1):

Subhen,

WebDAV is a set of protocols which acts as extension to HTTP protocol.
It basically proposes additional HTTP methods (in addition to standard GET, PUT, POST) like PROPFIND , PROPPATCH etc.

You first need to determine what methods are you interested in? (I guess what you need is MOVE). 
Then find out a webserver which implements the WebDAV extension. 
You might also need a corresponding web client which supports the extension.

Also please consider that there are alternatives to using pure WebDAV.
check wikipedia page on WebDAV for reference